# Php and max_execution_time

Tags: php, nginx

I need to one of my script (not all) works only five second. And if execution not finished yet (within five seconds) it should be dropped.

So I use

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);
```

Also if I do

```
ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

it shows me five second, but script not interrupt after 5 seconds.

P.S

1. `safe_mode = off`
2. `nginx -> php-fpm`
3. `set_time_limit(5)` also has no effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function on **top** in your code as follows:

`set_time_limit(5)`

**NB:** If you dont place it on top of your code, supposed the php script has ran for 3 seconds and you called `set_time_limit(5)` so the total time of allowed execution would be 3+5 = 8 sec not 5sec as expected

**Update**

From php documentation:

> Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the
>   script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

Comment: Can you please activate php-fpm slow log and provide us with some output if your script is being loged

Comment: Besides can you post extract of your codes where you placed the `set_time_limit(5)`